# new line in empheq

Tags: line-breaking, empheq

I have a big equation that I want to split with empheq :

```
\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace =  - \oint_S \frac{\overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS - \oint_S \frac{ \overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS }]{align*}
  \text{si $V \in V_p$,}& 0  \\
  \text{si $V \notin V_p$,}& \vec{v}_p
\end{empheq}
```

I have tried to break my equation with `\\` and `\newline` but it doesn't work ... ?

Comment: ok, it works. Mico response is the simpliest for me. thank  you everyone

Comment: Just to explain why this does not work: what you essentially have here is similar to `\begin{equation*} \begin{aligned} TEXT\end{aligned} \} = RIGHT \end{equation*}`, so as the others have pointed out, you probably want to do this differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an `align*` environment and a single line break directive. I wouldn't autosize the parentheses, and I'd use `\bar` instead of `\overline`. For better legibility, if you're using Computer Modern as the document font, consider inserting `\,` (thinspace) if `\vec{r}` or `\vec{\xi}` is followed by a closing parenthesis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left.\begin{array}{ll}
\text{si $V \in V_p$,    } & 0  \\[1ex]
\text{si $V \notin V_p$, } & \vec{v}_p
\end{array}\right\} 
&= - \oint_S \frac{\bar{\bar{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}\bigl(\bar{\bar{\sigma}}(\vec{r}\,)\vec{n}\bigr)dS 
+ \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r}\,)\biggl(\frac{\bar{\bar{\bar{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\biggr)dS \\
&\quad - \oint_S \frac{ \bar{\bar{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}\bigl(\bar{\bar{\sigma}}(\vec{r}\,)\vec{n}\bigr)dS  
+ \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r}\,)\biggl(\frac{\bar{\bar{\bar{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\biggr)dS 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not with `empheq`, but with more standard tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\oov}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ooov}[1]{\overline{\overline{\overline{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \text{si $V \in V_p$,}    & 0  \\
  \text{si $V \notin V_p$,} & \vec{v}_p
\end{rcases}
=\begin{aligned}[t]
& - \oint_S \frac{\oov{G}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}
    (\oov{\sigma}(\vec{r})\vec{n})\,dS
  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\Biggl(\frac{\ooov{\Sigma}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}
    \vec{n}\Biggr)\,dS
\\
& - \oint_S \frac{ \oov{G}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}
    (\oov{\sigma}(\vec{r})\vec{n})\,dS  
  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\Biggl(\frac{\ooov{\Sigma}(\vec{r} -\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}
    \vec{n}\Biggr)\,dS
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some refinements, basically adding `\,` when a vector is immediately followed by a parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\oov}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ooov}[1]{\overline{\overline{\overline{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \text{si $V \in V_p$,}    & 0  \\
  \text{si $V \notin V_p$,} & \vec{v}_p
\end{rcases}
=\begin{aligned}[t]
& - \oint_S \frac{\oov{G}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}
    (\oov{\sigma}(\vec{r}\,)\vec{n}\,)\,dS
  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\Biggl(\,\frac{\ooov{\Sigma}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}
    \vec{n}\Biggr)\,dS
\\
& - \oint_S \frac{ \oov{G}(\vec{r} - \vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}
    (\oov{\sigma}(\vec{r}\,)\vec{n}\,)\,dS  
  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r}\,)\Biggl(\,\frac{\ooov{\Sigma}(\vec{r} -\vec{\xi}\,)}{8\pi \mu}
    \vec{n}\Biggr)\,dS
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this proposed alternative might suit, using stacks, rather than `empheq`??  Note I left the math in `\textstyle` as you originally had it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{empheq,tabstackengine}

\begin{document}

Was:

\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace =  - \oint_S \frac{\overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS - \oint_S \frac{ \overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS }]{align*}
  \text{si $V \in V_p$,}& 0  \\
  \text{si $V \notin V_p$,}& \vec{v}_p
\end{empheq}

Proposed:

\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  \text{si $V \in V_p$,}& 0  \\
  \text{si $V \notin V_p$,}& \vec{v}_p
\end{aligned}
\right\}=
\ensurestackMath{\Shortunderstack
{- \oint_S \frac{\overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS 
\\ 
-\oint_S \frac{ \overline{\overline{G}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\left(\overline{\overline{\sigma}}(\vec{r})\vec{n}\right)dS  + \oint_S \vec{v}(\vec{r})\left(\frac{\overline{\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}}(\vec{r}-\vec{\xi})}{8\pi \mu}\vec{n}\right)dS }}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the equation in `\displaystyle`, then

1. add `\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}` to the preamble;
2. change `\ensurestackMath` to `\ensureTABstackMath`; and
3. change `\Shortunderstack` to `\tabbedShortunderstack`.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variant, always with `rcases`, using  the `\widebar` command, borrowed from `mathabx`, and the bvector arrows from `esvect`, which look nicer than the basic `vec`, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[f]{esvect} %
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<5><6><7><8><9><10>
<10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>
mathx10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigboxvoid}{\mathop}{mathx}{"DC}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{rcases} \text{si } V ∈ V_p , & 0 \\
  \text{si }V ∉ V_p, & \vv{v}_p
  \end{rcases}
  = & - ∮_S \frac{\widebar{\widebar{G}}(\vv{r}-\vv{ξ})}{8πμ}\left(\widebar{\widebar{σ}}(\vv{r})\vv{n}\right)dS + ∮_S \vv{v}(\vv{r})\left(\frac{\widebar{\widebar{\widebar{Σ}}}(\vv{r}-\vv{ξ})}{8πμ}\vv{n}\right)dS \\
                                        & - ∮_S \frac{ \widebar{\widebar{G}}(\vv{r}-\vv{ξ})}{8πμ}\left(\widebar{\widebar{σ}}(\vv{r})\vv{n}\right)dS + ∮_S \vv{v}(\vv{r})\left(\frac{\widebar{\widebar{\widebar{Σ}}}(\vv{r}-\vv{ξ})}{8πμ}\vv{n}\right)dS
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]